# Can I prepend to derived classes from base class?

Tags: ruby

I want prepend module to all derived classes.

But boring that writes `prepend GenericFooException` to all files.

(gloomy tone.) How to easy way to write?

```rb
module GenericFooException
  class FooException < StandardError; end

  def perform
    super
  rescue FooException => e
    # The truth is that rails ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError with .cause 
    puts "[CATCH] #{e.class}"
  end
end

module Foo
  class Base
    prepend GenericFooException

    def perform
      raise RuntimeError
    end 
  end
end

# It is my best. but can not catch the FooException
module Foo
  class Alice < Base
    class AliceException < FooException; end

    def perform
      raise AliceException
    end
  end
end

# Work it.
module Foo
  class Bob < Base
    prepend GenericFooException
    class BobException < FooException; end

    def perform
      raise BobException
    end
  end
end

Foo::Alice.new.perform #=> (exception)Foo::Alice::AliceException
Foo::Bob.new.perform #=> (output)[CATCH] Foo::Bob::BobException
```

Comment: You could use `inherited` hook.

Comment: Since there's a `perform` method and you mention a Rails error – is your question related to Active Job?

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I use `self.inherited` and `child.prepend`